# Decode JWT and put "sub" into a request header

Tags: istio

I’m using the Istio OPA adapter to manage AuthN and AuthZ. Some of my backend services need to know who is making a given request; for example, to populate a created_by column when a given user creates something.

I’m trying to figure out an elegant way of decoding the JWT and putting the “sub” field into a “user” header before the request gets sent to the actual backend service. This way, a given service would simply need to look at the “user” header rather than dealing with parsing the JWT.

Any ideas or recommendations on how this could be accomplished are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add headers with Lua code in an [EnovyFilter](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/envoy-filter/) or with a Mixer filter starting in Istio 1.1.

Take a look at this issue which describes some experimenting with adding headers extracted from JWT fields to affect routing:

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8444.